# Firebase getInstance always throwing No virtual method Exception

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am integrating Firebase realtime database inside my app, I followed the adding instructions, but it's always throwing exception

> No virtual method

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: appsTest.test, PID: 17680
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzcnu()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/appsTest.test-2/base.apk:classes15.dex)
      at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
      at appsTest.test.inAppViews.newsFeedScreen.NewsFeedFragment.<init>(NewsFeedFragment.java:31)
      at appsTest.test.inAppViews.BaseActivity.onClickOnTab(BaseActivity.java:144)
      at appsTest.test.inAppViews.BaseActivity.onTabSelected(BaseActivity.java:258)
      at com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar.sendListenerCall(BottomNavigationBar.java:578)
      at com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar.selectTabInternal(BottomNavigationBar.java:558)
      at com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar.access$000(BottomNavigationBar.java:44)
      at com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationBar$1.onClick(BottomNavigationBar.java:502)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6213)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23645)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

App module gradle:

```
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // this code at the end of gradle file
```

Initializing FireBase Database inside fragment at the OnCreate method:

```
    DatabaseReference mRootRefernce = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // at this line the exception happened
    DatabaseReference reference = mRootRefernce.child("feed");
```

Comment: All your Firebase dependencies should be at the same version.  Why are you using + for one of them?  Also, the stated version 9.6.1 is really old.  Your buildscript dependencies are rather old as well.  Check the documentation for the latest.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Comment: @DougStevenson
you are right about the + dependancy, I fixed it, also I tried the setup steps from firebase for android (the provided link) but it's throwing gradle error:

 
Thanks but it's still not working. I tried it and it's giving me this Gradle error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at bintray.com/android/android-tools/…) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's fixed by the following:

1. use the same version for Google play services (3.1.0)
2. update all libraries that depend on older version of Google play services, and it's in my case OneSignal library to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest version of firebase.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
```

google services:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

in app/build.gradle do you have below in the end?

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still not working.
I tried it and it's giving me this Gradle error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Comment: @WaelAbo-Aishah OK, try to remove apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' and try again